# Asciidoctor-pdf no parsing

Tags: asciidoctor-pdf

First, thank you for this great resource.  Beautiful pdf files it creates.

I have a bunch of text files with all kinds of text of which some are jebrish.   Some text lines start with a dot, etc.

Asciidoctor-pdf barfs on many pages correctly so.   I've spend days trying to clean the text files with sed but its a no end game.

Is there a way to tell Asciidoctor-pdf to  simply convert the text document to pdf without parsing it with Asciidoctor-pdf command options?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new AsciiDoc file where you include the text files using the [include macro](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/directives/include/). If you want the converter to ignore the syntax you should use a [passthrough block](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/pass/pass-block/). If you want to display a `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt` inside an `allfiles.adoc` it could look like this:

**allfiles.adoc**

```
= all files

== content of fileA.txt

++++
include::fileA.txt[]
++++

== content of fileB.txt

++++
include::fileB.txt[]
++++
```